# Metareg output: is Beta effect size or mean difference?

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I conducted a metaregression using metareg on a number of studies with a continuous outcomes measure which was temperature. I created forrest plots where the outcomes metric was mean difference. I then conducted a metaregression with respect to a categorical variable which was Neuromuscular which had levels: [yes, no, unreported].

My question is, is my Beta for neuromuscular estimate Yes (0.28) and Not reported (0.27) in the units of Effect size or Mean difference (in my case temperature)?
Thank you kindly for your thoughts.

[image: Metareg Output]

Comment: The units will be whatever you supplied to metareg. If you supplied it with mean differences that is what it is using as the effect size.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much mdewey